# As of now there were

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

In the following sentence

> [As of now Aadhaar enrolment and updating **were** being carried out at 48 centres in select offices in the city.](https://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Madurai/fourth-anniversary-of-digital-india/article28254385.ece)

When the sentence is in the present tense as indicated by **as of now** then why is **were used here**. I think it should be **is**

Comment: Because of subject-verb agreement. X and Y *were*, but X *was*. The use of *as of now* plays no role whatsoever in that.

Comment: I think the question is about the tense rather than the verb form _per se_. They are asking about **were** vs. **are** (rather than about **were** vs **is** as they said).

Answer (score 2):

As a native UK English speaker, if I were writing that sentence, I would probably use **are** instead of **were** or **is** — i.e. *As of now, Aadhaar enrolment and updating **are** being carried out at 48 centres in select offices in the city.*

The use of the term, *"enrollment **and** updating"* suggests more than one action (hence not **is**), and the use of *"As of now"* suggests present tense, rather than past (hence not **were**).

As for *why* the original author chose to use *were*, I couldn't reasonably say — perhaps it is a stylistic choice common to Indian newspaper writing, rather than one that I would expect to see in the UK.  Alternatively, it may have been a direct quote that was not expressly indicated.

Personally, I would not have structured that sentence in the same way as the original author.  I might have written it as *"Aadhaar<sup>1</sup> is presently carrying out enrollment and updating activities at 48 centres within the city"*.  However, I would not be writing for the same target audience, so I cannot be certain that my edits would express the same information.

<sup>1</sup> I have presumed that Aadhaar refers to a single organisation or department, hence the singular *is*.

Comment: As a native American speaker, I concur. It's probably just simple oversight.